SVG rotate="auto" is not behaving as predicted
I am attempting to animate a sprout growing. The plan is that the leaves should follow the path of the stem (illustrated with a dotted line). This is now working (with a little trial and error). However, I would like the leaves to rotate (from bottom-center) along with the path (ideally, growing as they move).
When I set rotate to "auto", the result is not what I would have predicted.


<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" stroke-dasharray="5" id="stem" d="m 29.7,149.1
c 0.3,-1 1.7,-8.6 -0.7,-20.1 -4.3,-20.6 -5.7,-48.9 42.1,-52"/>
  <path id="leaves" d="M 8.5,132.8
C 14.3,133 16.4,132.5 19.9,135.4 23.2,138.2 29.6,144.2 28.5,148.6
L 29.6,149 30.4,149.2
C 32.6,144.2 35.2,140.7 39.3,137.4 43.7,133.9 49.6,133.2 56.9,133.1 56.9,133.1 47.1,126.3 39.5,129.3 31.1,132.8 33.8,138.4 29.7,148.4 29.6,143.6 27.9,132 22.8,130 16.5,127.5 8.5,132.7 8.5,132.7
Z">
      <animateMotion
        dur="1s"
        repeatCount="1"
        rotate="auto"
        begin="leaves.click" fill="freeze" path="M 0,0
C 0.3,-1 1.7,-8.6 -0.7,-20.1 -5,-40.7 -6.4,-69 41.400002,-72.1"/>
</path>
</svg>



I assumed there may be issues with the path, so I have tried using relative and absolute paths, but both give the same result.

The present x/y position of an animated element is interpreted as offsets. See also "Offset when following svg motion path". In other words: you need to position the animated element around the zero-origin as the motion path animation won't auto-align this element

Altered all paths with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

multiply by 10 to get rid of .n decimal notation but keep accuracy

made all paths relative notation

increased viewBox by 10

changed leaves so the "stem" originates at 0,0 origin
!! this is important to get the rotate animation at the correct location
Requires the d-path to start at m160 -210 because the leaves start to draw from a leave... not the stem

rotated the leaves an extra 90 degrees, so they point over the x-axis (animation direction)


changed viewBox so the whole animation is visible

visibility trick to prevent a FOUC on the leaves (now initially drawn at 0,0 origin)




<svg width="150" viewBox="-200 -200 1200 1200" style="background:pink">
  <path id="stem" fill="none" 
        stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" stroke-dasharray="50" 
        d="m297 750c3-10 17-86-7-201-43-206-57-489 421-520"/>
  <path id="leaves" visibility="hidden" fill="green"
        d="m160-210c-2 58 3 79-26 114-28 33-88 97-132 86l-4 11-2 8
           c50 22 85 48 118 89 35 44 42 103 43 176 0 0 68-98 38-174-35
           -84-91-57-191-98 48-1 164-18 184-69 25-63-27-143-27-143z">
    <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin=".01s" />
    <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="3s"
                   rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze">
       <mpath href="#stem"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </path>
</svg>




This looks excellent, thank you. I am not sure about how the positioning works. Could you please further explain why the leaves needed to be rotated?
Obviously, this not part of the question, but do you know if it possible to scale the leaves while they move?

The leaves will animate over your path, but the direction info is that x-axis (see above screenshot). Your original leaves pointed "up" thus where rotated 90 degrees in the "wrong" direction
